# Simple fetch JSON data in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, json

So I got this JSON response:

```
{
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "full_name": "John Donovan",
            "username": "j.donovan"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get the "full_name" and "username" values.

What I have done is this (I got a "message" value):

```
axios.post('http://localhost/user/login', sendData)
        .then((result) => {         
            if (result.data.message === 'OK') {

                console.log(result.data.username});
            }
        })
```

I successfully get the value of "message" but failed to get the value for "full_name" and "username". The result for console.log above is "undefined".

Tried googling and searching in this forum still have not found the answer. Please your correction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is an array. need to access the index

```
console.log(result.data.data[0].username})
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much Sachila! Finally, I can get the value.